# How to deal HTTP GET parameters with special characters like '&', '?', '=' ...?

Tags: http, url, encoding

I am developing a java web project.

How to deal HTTP GET parameters with special characters like `&`, `?`, `=` ...?

For example, I have one parameter with one parameter `para1` whose value is `this?is&para=1`:

```
GET http://www.example.com/?para1=this?is&para=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to encode the characters that look like delimiters but are not using the algorithm in http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm. And no, that's not specific to HTTP but to HTML form submission types.

Comment: Your server language eg python and the client  javascript have functions for url encoding described above

Comment: Sorry - I know url encoding as I've used it to replace e.g. " " with %20. I just assumed the same method would be used to escape special characters but when I think about it that doesn't make sense - thanks for pointing that out